# SQL Server Return just 1 row from total matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, having

I made a query that matches the product dimensions of a product in our warehouse with the dimensions of our new stock locations. Example output below:

---

```
ArticleNr   Location    Packaging   StockAtLocation NewPackaging    Ranking

0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            33            10
0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            E2            11
0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            E3            12
0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            KK            13
0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            C4            14

0066487     A20057A03       KK           12             KK            13
0066487     A20057A03       KK           12             C4            14
```

---

Example: Product 0012953 is currently packaged in an 'MB' but in the new warehouse it can fit in 33, E2, E3, KK and C4. If it can fit in multiple locations, it should go into the one with the lowest ranking. In this case it should go to NewPackaging '33' with Ranking 10.

Product 0066487 should go to KK with ranking 13.

How can I tweak the query to that it only returns the record with the lowest ranking per ArticleNr?

---

Desired Output:

```
ArticleNr   Location    Packaging   StockAtLocation NewPackaging    Ranking

0012953     A15074E03       MB           235            33            10
0066487     A20057A03       KK           12             KK            13
```

---

Query:

```
SELECT
  t1.ArticleNr,
  t1.Location AS Location,
  t1.StorageMedium AS Packaging,
  t1.StockAtLocation,
  t2.Verpakking AS NewPackaging,
  t2.Ranking
FROM #Info t1,
     #Dimensions t2
WHERE t1.Length < t2.Lengte 
AND t1.Width < t2.Breedte 
AND t1.Height < t2.Hoogte 
AND t1.Volume < t2.MaxVol 
AND (t1.PartWeightGross / 1000) < t2.MaxWeightArt 
AND (t1.Volume * t1.StockAtLocation) < t2.MaxVol 
AND ((t1.PartWeightGross / 1000) * t1.StockAtLocation) < t2.MaxWeightEmb 
Order by ArticleNr asc, Ranking asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ROW_NUMBER to the Select and select where Row_number = 1.

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ArticleNr ORDER BY ArticleNr asc, Ranking asc),
  t1.ArticleNr,
  t1.Location AS Location,
  t1.StorageMedium AS Packaging,
  t1.StockAtLocation,
  t2.Verpakking AS NewPackaging,
  t2.Ranking
FROM #Info t1,
     #Dimensions t2
WHERE t1.Length < t2.Lengte 
AND t1.Width < t2.Breedte 
AND t1.Height < t2.Hoogte 
AND t1.Volume < t2.MaxVol 
AND (t1.PartWeightGross / 1000) < t2.MaxWeightArt 
AND (t1.Volume * t1.StockAtLocation) < t2.MaxVol 
AND ((t1.PartWeightGross / 1000) * t1.StockAtLocation) < t2.MaxWeightEmb 
)
select
    *
    from cte
        where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks that works lovely, Im sure Ill have to use that again in the future